# Remove cookies completely from device

Tags: android, cookies, cookiemanager

I am using CookieManager to store cookies. Now, there is also time when I remove cookies. I am doing it by `CookieManager.removeAllCookies()`. As I have seen, It removes cookies for sure but Its storage size in device is same as it is.

For, i.e. by storing cookies app size is 3 MB and after removing cookies, its size does nt decreased.

Is there any way by which we can remove it ???

**Code :**

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
cm = CookieManager.getInstance();
cm.setAcceptCookie(true);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
cm.removeAllCookie();
```

Comment: show the code that removes the cookies..

Comment: Read this, it will help you--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896993/cookiemanager-getinstance-removeallcookie-doesnt-remove-all-cookies

Answer (score 0):

call :

```
  CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

After calling this function:

```
  cm.removeAllCookie();
```

Comment: I did it but still cookie size is same as before.

Comment: before removing cookies, its size was 5.96 MB and after removing it, its size is same as 5.96 MB. If i click on clear data in mobile device then only it removes all data.