# Activity lifecycle with two activities

Tags: android

Suppose `Activity1` starts, and then it starts `Activity2`. `Activity2` performs some task and ends. What
minimal sequence of activity lifecycle methods would be invoked during this? Prefix activity
lifecycle calls with the associated activity. In other words, start your sequence with
`Activity1.onCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

Try here first https://stackoverflow.com/a/5538421/3720591

This is a easy to find question though, also somewhat demanding lol.

Answer (score 0):

```
Activity1.onCreate()
Activity1.onStart()
Activity1.onResume()
//intent for Activity2
//finish() method not called here
Activity2.onCreate()
Activity2.onStart()
Activity2.onResume()
//Activity2 performs tasks
//finish() method called
Activity2.onPause()
Activity2.onStop()
Activity2.onDestroy()
Activity1.onResume()
//Activity1 can perform task again
```