# Music player - activity lifecycle

Tags: android, audio-player, activity-lifecycle, android-music-player

I have really hard time with background music in my app. I just want to play music in all activities - when I press home button I want to stop music.  I want "stop or play" music button in all activities, but couldn´t make it work.

So I decided to make embarassing choice - play it only in 1 activitiy by

onCreate

```
    backgroundmusic = MediaPlayer.create(StoryActivity.this, R.raw.creepy_music);
    backgroundmusic.start();
```

onPause

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    backgroundmusic.release();
    finish();
}
```

Can you please help me with easy activity lifecycle? So when a user presses home button - music will stop. When he will come back to app - music will be restored and this activity too **(it is not MainActivity)**

Thank you, guys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest Android Activity Lifecycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538312/simplest-android-activity-lifecycle)

Comment: You can play music from Service and manage stream from Activity. Here's a good tutorial about that: http://sapandiwakar.in/building-a-music-player-app-for-android-2/

Comment: In that case music won't be attached to one activity only and you can manage from anywhere

Comment: @НикитаХлебушкин I tried a lot of types of services for this music manager, but I will give this one a try :) Thank you

Comment: @НикитаХлебушкин It is exactly what I am trying few hours to do... I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Here are the different LifeCycle states. Now to your answer,

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        backgroundmusic.pause();
        length = backgroundmusic.getCurrentPosition();  
    }

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        backgroundmusic.seekTo(length);
        backgroundmusic.start();
    }
```

In `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`, It's the AppCompatActivity that is the main source of an Activity's functionality, hence in the above methods like `super.onResume();` and `super.onStop();` super refers to the `AppCompatActivity class`

Answer (score 0):

assume that you can get the music service in the Application ,you may be looking for this :

```
 public class MyApp extends Application{

MusicService musicService;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
            if(musicService==null) return;
            if(!musicService.isPlaying()){
                musicService.play();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
             if(musicService==null) return;
             if(musicService.isPlaying()){
                musicService.pause();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Hope this helps